# contribution pages and mailings have incorrect URLs

Tags: urls, resource-urls

I don't know when it began, but these pages all used to work on some version of these site.
I currently look after 3 different CiviCRM installations for different non-profits.

On one of them (running WP 5.4 and Civi 25.0) links to Contribution pages work:

```
https://sitename.tld/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=1&action=preview
```

On another (running WP 5.5, Civi 5.24.6), a contribution link menu now produces:

```
https://site2.tld/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=8
```

This works if I'm logged in, but is not publically available. It used to offer up this link instead:

```
https://site2.tld/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=8
```

If I edit the link to remove the wp-admin/admin.php section, then I get an empty page. If I use the ID in the civicontribute shortcode on another page, it works ok (though has another problem I will not muddle the is question with).

A third site (running WP 5.5, Civi 5.23) has a similar problem. The URLs are created correctly on that one, but the resulting page is empty whether a contribution page or a "public view" of a mailing.

Lastly a site using WP 5.5 and Civi 5.28 has the new civiwp URL structure but still won't respond to the page request. I have to use the shortcode in a WP page.

```
https://onothersite.tld/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=1
```

I mention these together because I don't think it is a version issue so much as I have somehow allowed some common problem to creep into these sites. I am especially mystified that I cannot seem to even manually construct a URL that is being correctly answered.

Thoughts I have had, but have not found info on:

- possible missing rewrite info in .htaccess,
- Theme interference, though one of the non-working ones is running the same theme as the working one.

UPDATE: I have tried enabling the wordpress ["Clean URL" system](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/install/wordpress/#enabling-cleaner-urls-for-wordpress) on one site. It seemed to work in that it pointed at the default civicrm page, but I still get no content:

```
https://sitename.tld/civicrm/?id=6df8f11af7cc1a8a&reset=1.
```

I would really appreciate any thoughts people might have as to where to look. This is becoming a serious problem.

Comment: you may want to hop on to https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/wordpress since it sounds like it could take some teasing apart